# Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему в `.attr()` тригерится ошибка `Unexpected token -`? Где там вообще дефис?

```
$('.alert-button').off('click').attr({
    data-inverted: '',
    data-tooltip: 'Чтобы начать новый поиск, <a href="#" class="reload-page">перезагрузите</a> страницу',
    data-position: 'bottom center'
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Где там вообще дефис?

В свойствах переданного объекта.

Ключи литерала объекта, которые не являются валидными идентификаторами, должны быть строковыми литералами:

```
$('.alert-button').off('click').attr({
    "data-inverted": '',
    "data-tooltip": 'Чтобы начать новый поиск, <a href="#" class="reload-page">перезагрузите</a> страницу',
    "data-position": 'bottom center'
});
```